# 'DynamicArr<T>::operator =' : unable to match function definition to an existing declaration

Tags: c++

I have this prototype in my class header:

```
DynamicArr<T> & operator=(const DynamicArr<T> &);
```

and I'm using this code in my class:

```
template <class T>
DynamicArr<T>& DynamicArr<T>::operator=(DynamicArr<T>& da){
   doStuff();
   return *this;
}
```

but for some reason it doesn't match my prototype. So what's wrong?

Comment: Templates should be in headers....

Comment: This is pretty vague regarding what the problem is. Please explain what you mean by "for some reason it doesn't match my prototype". Are you getting any error messages?

Comment: I'm getting the error message from the title

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot `const` in the parameter.

Also you have to put the implementation in your header file otherwise the compiler may not be able to instantiate the template.